# Replacement of One of the Faulty Master Node in Kubernetes Cluster with New Server/node

Tags: kubernetes

I need your help for one of the scenario where in our 3-Node Master K8s cluster, one of the Master(Master-2)node  corrupted and not coming up.

Hence we decided to replace this Faulty Master-2 node with fresh server node as Master-2.

So I need your suggestion and references how this can be achieved step by step on Production env smoothly.

As it is production environment so we can not take direct risk of customer impact hence want to be little more  preventive hence team here will  definitely suggest best approach.

Comment: Usually it's as simple as redploying the configuration with whatever tool you used to set up the cluster.